# use the method of extended class and of derived

Tags: c++

Let's say i have a class named `Foo` and a class named `Bar` that extends `Foo`.
I store them in a vector by pointer:

```
class Foo {

    void draw() {
        // stuff
    }   

};

class Bar() : public Foo {

    void draw() {
        // stuff
    }

}


vector<Foo*> someVector;
// put types of Foo and Bar in the vector

for (int i = 0; i < someVector.size(); i++) {
    Foo &f = someVector[i];
    // if it's of type bar it should
    // use that draw method
    f.draw();
}
```

Now it will always use the draw method of `Foo`. But how can i let it use the draw method of `Bar` if it's of type Bar?

edit:
Thanks to Joe Z i know this can be done now with virtual. But what if it is of type 'Bar' and i want to use the draw method of 'Foo'? Now with the virtual it always picks the 'Bar' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `virtual` methods.  This tells the compiler to use polymorphic dispatch (ie. look up at run time the correct method to call).

```
class Foo {

    virtual void draw() {
        // stuff
    }   

};

class Bar : public Foo {

    virtual void draw() {
        // stuff
    }
};
```

This looks like a reasonable tutorial explaining the concept: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/

Comment: Thanks it works. But what if it is of type `Bar` and i want to use the `Bar` draw method?

Comment: Calling `->draw()` will dispatch to the appropriate `draw()` method for the type.  Suppose you have `Bar *x`, then `x->draw()` will call `Bar::draw()`.  That is, assuming `x` points to a `class Bar` object (which it will, unless you introduce a new class that derives from `Bar`, in which case `x` could point to a derived class.)

Comment: Is it possible to have `x->draw()` call `Foo::draw()` ?

Comment: @clankill3r : Not through a `Bar *`, because `Bar` is a derived class.  But the implementation for `Bar::draw()` can call `Foo::draw()` to do some of its work if it needs to.  (That is `x->draw()` calls `Bar::draw()`, and then `Bar::draw()` calls `Foo::draw()` internally.)

Comment: thanks. I just made a method drawTechnical. Seems the best solution in my case.